# Is it safe to set a view's value in awakeFromNib?

Tags: macos, cocoa

Is it safe to do the following?

```
// in AppController.h
@interface AppController : NSObject
{
    IBOutlet NSTextField *label;
}
@end

// in AppController.m
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [label setIntValue:5];
}
```

Or is there a chance that `label` might not yet have been fully initialised when `awakeFromNib` is sent to the `AppController` instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSNibAwaking_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) says:

> Important
> Because the order in which objects are instantiated from an archive is not guaranteed, your initialization methods should not send messages to other objects in the hierarchy. **Messages to other objects can be sent *safely* from within awakeFromNib—by which time it’s assured that all the objects are unarchived and initialized** (though not necessarily awakened, of course).

In Fact, awakeFromNib is send to all objects the nib created **and** File's Owner , after creation of the objects and connecting outlets and actions is complete.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is safe. 
But you should use `viewDidLoad:` for any view setup after the loading of the nib file.